# Add padding to a single div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

How can I add padding to the top of a single `div`? Is there a way to do it without modifying the `.css` file? I am using `Bootstrap` and there is no space between the `carousel` and the first `div`. I tried adding padding to the `carousel`, but the color of the left and right chevron overlap the padding, and this is not the look I want. I want a true white space between the two.

Comment: DEMO USING JSFIDDLE WOULD BE APPRECIATED MOST SIMPLE CASE WOULD BE TO ADD A CLASS WITH REQUIRED CSS PROPERTY TO THE REQUIRED DIV BUT

Comment: Without playing with the CSS? You mean, without CSS? Then add a `<br>`.

Comment: Please mate, refrain to comment all in caps. I thought that by now everybody knows that not only you don't make your comment more "readed" but insteed people won't read it at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `<div style="padding-top: 10px;">` :)

Comment: Technically this is playing with css :)

Answer (score 2):

Use firebug on Chrome or Firefox and see which div or element inside the carousel needs the padding you want.

However, the best way would be to use CSS. As you said, you want a padding, and CSS has the padding property. As @Jorgen said, just add a padding top.

Otherwise use `<br>` instead as @Mr Lister said